# How to render specific tree nodes in Angular Material flat tree based on a node property?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

I wanna display specific tree nodes `<mat-tree-node>` based on a node's `nodeAuthorized: boolean` property. How can I achieve this since angular does not allow more than 2 structural directives on a single element.

I've tried using the `nodeAuthorized` property on the only child `<div>` of `<mat-tree-node>`, but this renders an empty space between 2 or more tree nodes. Any help would be appreciated?

This is what I've tried but, this leaves an obvious empty space between nodes which I don't want.

```
<mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
 <div *ngIf="node.treeNode.nodeAuthorized">   
  <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle>
   <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
    {{
       treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? "expand_more" : "chevron_right"
     }}
    </mat-icon>
   </button>

   {{node.treeNode.nodeName}}
 </div>
</mat-tree-node>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*matTreeNodeDef` can be used with `<ng-container>` which can then be used with another HTML element say `<div>` and structural directive `*ngIf` to render specific nodes.

```
<ng-container *matTreeNodeDef="let node">
    <ng-container *ngIf="node.authorized"> /** node rendering condition goes here */
      <mat-tree-node matTreeNodePadding>
        <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle>
          <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
            {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
          </mat-icon>
        </button>
        {{node.name}}
      </mat-tree-node>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: Can you please share an example of this?

Comment: @Chandermani I have updated my answer with am example.